# Do I have to get each collection achievement from the Claptrap DLC in a single playthrough?

Tags: achievements, borderlands, borderlands-claptraps-revolution

I'm trying to get the following achievements:

- The Lubricator
- Bobble-Trap
- It's so realistic
- What a party!

It is taking forever to get some of these.  Do I have to do this with in one playthrough?  What about if I collect these in multiple playthroughs but with the same character?  Is it cumulative over all my characters and all my playthroughs in my save game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to get them in one playthrough.  It is a ton of grinding.  Use the hiding spot.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what "the hiding spot" is?

Comment: @Mufasa - on the boss fight in Arid Badlands at the end of the DLC there's a corner you can get into where only one of the gatling guns can hit you. Take it out and then leave it for a bit, when you come back the boss will have trampled a load of the regular claptraps for a ton of parts.